# Pressure waves for sounds

Tags: energy, pressure, acoustics

Is it possible to mechanically create a pressure wave, with correct amplitude, frequency, and other noise characteristics to recreate known sounds like train horns, chime bells, gun shot, etc.?

I am interested if a vibrating body, driven by a computer with controlled forces at various places in the body, can create a specific sound that a human will recognize, even though it doesn't have any of the properties of that material.

For example, is it possible to create a train horn noise by connecting a computer to a metal plate that can create pressure waves or multiple air tubes interfering constructively? Would this noise be able to be indistinguishable to the human ear from a real train horn? Can this be done by stacking a lot of air tubes with different frequencies and amplitudes?

Comment: Isn't that what audio speakers do?

Comment: @Hilbert Yes it would seem so. Josh, what is different from what you are asking about and typical audio speakers, head phones, etc.?

Comment: A chime bell is a mechanical system already. Make a piece of metal the right shape, and hit it with something!

Comment: @alephzero The OP wants something that can recreate many types of sounds.

Answer (score 1):

A device that does this is called a *synthesizer*. It can be programmed to emulate many types of sounds fairly well, but complicated sounds like the human voice are harder to synthesize.